# Get the position of xml element in SQL Server 2012

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to get the row number for the rows using SQL Server 2012?

Here is the xml

```
<Rows>
   <Row>Coating</Row>
   <Row>Drying</Row>
   <Row>Waxing</Row>
</Rows>
```

I need data returned like this

```
RowLabel  RowNumber
-------------------
Coating    1
Drying     2
Waxing     3
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use some internal knowledge about how SQL Server implements XML shredding and use `row_number()` like this.

```sql
declare @XML xml = 
'<Rows>
   <Row>Coating</Row>
   <Row>Drying</Row>
   <Row>Waxing</Row>
</Rows>'

select T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RowLabel,
       row_number() over(order by T.X) as RowNumber
from @XML.nodes('/Rows/Row') as T(X)
```

Ref: [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx)

Or you can "play it safe" and use a numbers table.

```sql
select T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RowLabel,
       N.Number as RowNumber
from Numbers as N
  cross apply @XML.nodes('/Rows/Row[sql:column("N.Number")]') as T(X)
where N.Number between 1 and @XML.value('count(/Rows/Row)', 'int')
```

Comment: A working link is [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://dataeducation.com/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense_rank/)
(yes, I tried to edit, but got: suggested edit queue is full)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way **within XQuery** to return the position of the current node: you can count all nodes previous to it

```sql
SELECT T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RowLabel,
       T.X.value('let $i := . return count(/Rows/Row[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as RowNumber
FROM @xml.nodes('/Rows/Row') as T(X);
```

What this does is:

- Assign the current node to the variable `$i`
- Takes all the nodes in `/Rows/Row` that are *previous* to `$i` and counts them
- Then add 1 to make it one-based

In some situations you may not want to go back to the root node, in which case you can use the `..` parent axis

```sql
SELECT T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RowLabel,
       T.X.value('let $i := . return count(../Row[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as RowNumber
FROM @xml.nodes('/Rows/Row') as T(X);
```

You can also count backwards from the end by changing to `>>`.

[**dbfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a98f77e9ae0eb96fb3e53cf36495f67d)