# Row numbers when shredding XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, shred

I'm trying to add row numbers in the `DAY_VALUE` column that reset after each `inventorymodel`. I have a start, but I can't them to reset or count up instead of having ties. It would look something like this:

| DEMANDPERCENT | INVENTORYMODEL_ID | DAY_VALUE | STOCKPERDAY | SUPPLY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15.0000000953 | Default | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | Default | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | Default | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 14.2857151031 | Test | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 14.2857151031 | Test | 2 | 0 | 0 |

```
INSERT INTO #SYS_MYS_INVENTORYMODELDAYS(
    DEMANDPERCENT,
    INVENTORYMODEL_ID,
    DAY_VALUE,
    STOCKPERDAY,
    SUPPLY
)
SELECT
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('DemandPercent').value('.', 'float'),
    InvModel.inventorymodel.value('@id', 'nvarchar(255)'),
    InvModel.inventorymodel.value('let $i := . return count(/inventorymodels/inventorymodel/inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday[. << $i]) + 1', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('StocksPerDay').value('.', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('Supply').value('.', 'int')
FROM(
    SELECT CAST(InvModels AS xml)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\Users\owjo1001\AppData\Local\Nielsen\Spaceman\Config\InvModels.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(InvModels)
) AS T(InvModels)
CROSS APPLY InvModels.nodes('inventorymodels/inventorymodel') AS InvModel(inventorymodel)
CROSS APPLY InvModel.inventorymodel.nodes('inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday') AS InvModels(inventorymodelday)
```

```
  <inventorymodel id="Default">
    <inventorymodeldays count="7">
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>15.0000009536743</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>10</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>11</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>12</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>13</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>19</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>1</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>20</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
    </inventorymodeldays>
    <MovementStores>1</MovementStores>
    <MovementDays>7</MovementDays>
    <SafetyStockType>0</SafetyStockType>
    <SafetyStockDays>0</SafetyStockDays>
    <SafetyStockPercent>0</SafetyStockPercent>
    <UseDemandVariance>0</UseDemandVariance>
    <DemandVariance>0</DemandVariance>
    <UseCaseMultiple>1</UseCaseMultiple>
    <CaseMultiple>1.25</CaseMultiple>
    <UseManualInventory>0</UseManualInventory>
    <SetAsDefault>1</SetAsDefault>
    <HistoricalServiceLevel>0.899999976158142</HistoricalServiceLevel>
    <TargetServiceLevel>0.949999988079071</TargetServiceLevel>
  </inventorymodel>
  <inventorymodel id="Test">
    <inventorymodeldays count="7">
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday><inventorymodels count="2">
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>1</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>14.2857151031494</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>1</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
    </inventorymodeldays>
    <MovementStores>1</MovementStores>
    <MovementDays>7</MovementDays>
    <SafetyStockType>0</SafetyStockType>
    <SafetyStockDays>0</SafetyStockDays>
    <SafetyStockPercent>0</SafetyStockPercent>
    <UseDemandVariance>1</UseDemandVariance>
    <DemandVariance>0.100000001490116</DemandVariance>
    <UseCaseMultiple>0</UseCaseMultiple>
    <CaseMultiple>0</CaseMultiple>
    <UseManualInventory>0</UseManualInventory>
    <SetAsDefault>0</SetAsDefault>
    <HistoricalServiceLevel>0.899999976158142</HistoricalServiceLevel>
    <TargetServiceLevel>0.949999988079071</TargetServiceLevel>
  </inventorymodel>
</inventorymodels>
```

Comment: `row_number() over(partition by  InvModel.inventorymodel order by InvModels.inventorymodelday)` … `InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('let $i := . return count(../inventorymodelday[. << $i])+1')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea based on [Get the position of xml element in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836226/get-the-position-of-xml-element-in-sql-server-2012) (which is similar to lptr's comment above)

Note that row_number() seemingly works here, but the order is not guaranteed there.

```
SELECT
    InvModel.inventorymodel.value('@id', 'varchar(100)'),
    InvModels.*

FROM(
    SELECT CAST(InvModels AS xml)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\Users\owjo1001\AppData\Local\Nielsen\Spaceman\Config\InvModels.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(InvModels)

) AS T(InvModels)
CROSS APPLY InvModels.nodes('inventorymodels/inventorymodel') AS InvModel(inventorymodel)
cross apply (
select row_number() over(order by (select null)),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.value('DemandPercent[1]', 'float'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.value('StocksPerDay[1]', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.value('Supply[1]', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.value('let $i := . return count(../inventorymodelday[. << $i])+1','int') DAY_VALUE
from 
invModel.inventoryModel.nodes('inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday')  as InvModels(inventorymodelday)
) as InvModels(DAY_VALUE_ROW_NUMBER,DemandPercent,StocksPerDay,Supply,DAY_VALUE)
```